# Is the complement of interval graph an interval graph also?

Tags: graph-theory

In Graph Theory, *IG* is an interval graph, then the question is: Is the complement of *IG* also an interval graph? if so, then  how can we prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true. The complement of this graph is not an interval graph (It is $C_4$), while the graph itself is an interval graph:

[image]

Comment: The graph has four vertices, I drew the edges crossed because I wanted to make it clear the complement is a $4$-cycle.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much, it is clear